# Buzzing when not playing

Tags: pulseaudio

I am using a fresh system with PulseAudio. This system previously did not have this issue when using GNOME, but with this reinstall I am using i3wm without a DE.

The issue is that after my analog audio output idles for a few seconds (between 5 and 10), it begins to buzz. As soon as something opens the audio device (including `pavucontrol`), the buzz goes away.

My suspicion is the device is being disabled after idling and some interference from the AC power source is causing the noise.

I don't want to have to make something hold ownership of the device, because sometimes I use other software that doesn't play nice with PulseAudio and I need it to access this device.

What can I do to remedy this behavior?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found in `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and `/etc/pulse/system.pa` a line:

```
load-module module-suspend-on-idle
```

After commenting these out, the problem is solved.

Comment: This solved the issue for me after trying different solutions! You're the best. That buzzing was irritating me

Comment: Worked for me on Fedora 33 on a Dell XPS laptop.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above may be everyone's solution but I also wanted to mention what fixed my buzzing when no audio was playing or when idling after a few seconds. Make sure your output device is correct! Haha, I have an external sound card that the system was for some reason defaulting to and created this same issue. Needed to change to Line Out.

Comment: This assumes that other users have a similar configuration, so it might not be relevant to everyone looking at this answer.